# Convert function call

Tags: web3js

I want to understand how function call should be converted to the hex.

I have to sign transaction on the client side. Web3 provides this function:

```
web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey)
```

Tx is transaction which has `data` field. Data field represents function call with arguments in `hex` format.

The question is how to convert function call into this hex representation? What kind of format I should follow?

At this moment I'm looking at this https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/abi-spec.html gives the gory details.

Essentially:

- The beginning of the `data` is the "function selector," the first four bytes of the keccak256 hash of the function signature, e.g., `keccak256("transfer(address,amount)"`.
- The rest is the ABI-encoded arguments. For simple types, it's pretty much just the raw value, and for things like arrays, it gets a bit more complicated. (Essentially a pointer to the data, then a size telling you how much data to read, and then the data itself.)

Comment: Thank you, Smarx! We already had a chat on this and I even worked on parser for this, but few examples in the web move my thoughts I missed something. Research on high level libraries brought me to this way to implement it https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/issues/344